# Facebook Graph API: Unable to reply a comment on unpublish page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

I'm using the Graph API Explorer to reply the comments on fan page via my app.
It works only the page is **published**. However, it bothers me so much.

**How do I to test the app before publishing the page?**

What I'm trying to do is the app will listen to the webhook from Facebook and then reply to the comment as long as got a comment.
I've been search for a while, there's very few questions related to this.  Any suggestion would be thankful. ;)

```
// POST
https://graph.facebook.com/{comment-id}/comments

// response when the page is unpublished
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#200) Cannot access object_id: {comment-id}",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 200,
    "fbtrace_id": "{fbtrace_id}"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed that you can't access the comments while unpublished as the page id prepends the comment id. I would say quickest and easiest way to test is to just create a separate test page and keep that published.

Comment: yeah~ but I don't want any of my friends to know the test page. Is it possible?

Comment: I'd then suggest creating a completely random test page, and in the page settings area, under "Country Restrictions", enter a random country that you know your friends don't live in. Only people who live in this country, and you, will be able to see the page, so you should be safe. Everyone else will get a "page not found" if they try visit the page and aren't from the country. (for example, if they somehow got the URL to the page)